# Converting base64 to pdf problem

Tags: base64

//This is solved. I was converting as pdf but below base64 is in ZIP type. I have changed the code as application/zip and solved!

I have a class that takes base64 string and I am converting this string to attachment as below code. When I try this code with my base64 of converted pdf, It works well. However, I have a base64 string that it can be converted online to pdf but my codes don't convert. What can I do?

```
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                attachment.ParentId = pdf.salesforceId;
                attachment.contentType = 'application/pdf'; 
                attachment.Name = 'invoice.pdf';
                attachment.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(pdf.pdfCode);
```

[pdf base64 string](https://justpaste.it/5rnqs)

Comment: What actual behavior do you see? Error message? Exception?

Comment: there is no error or exception. When I investigate the debug logs, there are no exceptions. File is created but when I try to open it online/on my computer, file doesn't open.

Comment: When I try to open on computer; "The file “invoice.pdf” could not be opened.
It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize."

Comment: We'd need to see what a sample payload looks like. Is it possible you could put the value from pdfCode in a pastebin or something?

Comment: pdfCode is very long this site doesn't accepts :/ How can I send its base64 codes to you?

Comment: I edited the question to show pdf. You can see from that link

Comment: In general, the body of a pdf should be a blob not a string.

Comment: Encoding method returns blob. What do you mean?